# Compare Two Data Frames and Update A Column

Tags: r

I understand how to compare two dataframes:

```
setdiff(df1,df2)
```

But is there away to compare a column and if it is different, update the value. So say in df1 I have

```
A  |  B
-------
a  |  3
b  |  7
c  |  8
```

And in df2 I have

```
A  |  B
-------
a  |  3
b  |  10
c  |  8
```

Is there a way to have the change in value (b has changed to 10) be applied to df1?

Comment: So you want `df1$B` and `df2$B` to be the same?

Comment: Yes but I don't want to just copy the entire row back in I want to be able to know exactly which entry is different so the response would tell me that row b has changed from 7 to 10 and then I can update df1 to be the same. If that makes any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
df1 = data.frame(A = c("a", "b", "c"),
                 B = c(3, 7, 8))

df2 = data.frame(A = c("a", "b", "c"),
                 B = c(3, 10, 8))


diff_index = which(df1$B != df2$B)
df1$B[diff_index] = df2$B[diff_index]
```

`diff_index` extracts the index where `df1$B` not equal to `df2$B`, then uses that index to replace `df1$B` with what's in `df2$B`

Answer (score 0):

df1 = data.frame(a=letters[1:3],b = c(3,7,8))

df2 = data.frame(a=letters[1:3],b = c(3,10,8))

```
df1$b[!(df1$b %in% df2$b)]=df2$b[!(df1$b %in% df2$b)]
```

Comment: This would be the same as just setting `df1$B = df2$B` in that you don't know which row(s) were modified.